# mount two hard drives on start up

Tags: mount, startup, drive

I have two hard-drives (one internal and one external) that I want to mount on start up (ntfs, but it doesn’t matter).

I can mount them fine with the "Disk Utility" aplication and I can mount them fine with the comands

> /usr/bin/udisks --mount /dev/disk/by-uuid/21318E3E64707B4D
>
> /usr/bin/udisks --mount /dev/disk/by-uuid/6439FB1D652606C4

respectively (I followed this tutorial; https://help.ubuntu.com/community/AutomaticallyMountPartitions#Per-User_Mounts and used the Per-User Mounts).

But when I put these commands, separated by a semicolon, in the Startup Application to run on startup, it only mounts one of the partitions (always the same one). Why is this and how to fix it?

(At first I tried to have each mounting-command as a separate "startup program" but then the start-up program removed one of the programs, leaving me with only one mounted hard drive...)

I'm using Ubuntu 12.04 LTS.

Thank's in advance!

Comment: from the link you pasted Adding to startup

`gnome-session-properties

Push the Add button.

Choose a name, paste in your command and push the Add button` what do you see in this gnome-session-screen ? are the two disks you want present there , if you remove the semicolon there and do add one by one do you get desired result

Comment: Hi, when press Add, paste my comand, and choose name and save, then I see both startup programs there. but when I exit the "startup application" and enter it again, I only see one, thus the startup program removed one of the programs...

Comment: Hmmm the external hard drive you mentioned is it always attached to your system or it is a portable device I tried the same on my system what I noticed is my disk got mounted at /dev/media what is the output  on terminal when you type
`/usr/bin/udisks --mount /dev/disk/by-uuid/21318E3E64707B4D`  where does it gets mounted and while it is mounted and you type in `/usr/bin/udisks --mount /dev/disk/by-uuid/6439FB1D652606C4` where does the second mount gets mounted does it go in same /media

Comment: Your link says  ` This method is only available in Hardy and Karmic.` and below it says to use pysdm package and when I checked pysdm package links http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2076532&p=12318955#post12318955 it says this package is obsolete so you need to manually edit the fstab file

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To mount hard drives on startup, you need to edit the `/etc/fstab` file. Just open the file in your favourite editor(be sure to use `sudo`)

> sudo gedit /etc/fstab

and add the appropriate lines for your hard drives

> UUID="UUID here"      /mount/point filesystem-type defaults 0 0

Just put in the UUID, mount point and filesystem type.
See [this](http://web.archive.org/web/20130413052717/http://www.tuxfiles.org/linuxhelp/fstab.html) for more info.

Comment: Great! That solved it! I also had to create a folder manually where I wanted them to be mounted, but everything was explained at your link! Thanks!

Comment: this link is now dead, also I am having the same problem but can not see any folder named "fstab". Only a fodler named "fstab.d" which seems to be empty. Could someone elaborate on what was done here?

Comment: @KalamalkaKid I fixed the link using wayback machine. `fstab` is not a folder, it's a file. Open it in an editor and add the line above.