# What are the advantages/disadvantages of different SSD to HDD cacheing options (dm-cache, flashcashe...)?

Tags: ssd, dm-cache, flashcache, bcache, enhanceio

There appear to be various different technologies available to use an SSD to act as a cache for HHDs. The ones I know of:

- dm-cache (by Redhat - in the 3.9 Kernel, so it should be in ubuntu 13.10)
- Flashcache (developed and used by  facebook)
- Bcache (developed and used by Google )
- EnhanceIO (by STEC; based on Flashcache)

Are there any noteworthy differences in the various implementations? 
Which one is best for regular desktop PC use - to increase performance of usual programs such as web browsers or games?

Comment: To increase performance I found that the installation of 64bit ubuntu, worked great, my machine got even faster than before! Also, about cache you should use ram compressed cache with this package `zram-config` that will get priority on swap usage. And, store the game on the SDD and test it up. Some games wont work much faster, others will work great! I prefer to not use SDD as cache because of its writes limit but SDDs are getting cheaper so thats not so much concern anymore :)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I really don’t know where to start, since all this is excellent information.  I will start with some info about SSD’s, then a description of all the different caching methods, and just go from there.  I hope that you

Advantages/Disadvantages

- Price: SSDs are somehow expensive
- Maximum and Common Capacity: High capacity SSD’s are very rare and
  expensive
- Speed: This is where SSDs gets the edge
- Durability: An SSD has no moving parts

Best to have a hybrid system, to have the best of both worlds (capacity, reliability, speed, etc.)

> The Linux 3.9 kernel (made available on April 28, 2013) introduces SSD
>   caching. The kernel's Device mapper now includes a cache target called
>   dm-cache that enables SSDs or other storage device to be used as a
>   cache for a hard drive. It essentially speeds up data writes and reads
>   as it allows the faster SSD to first cache data and then transfer it
>   to the slower hard drive.

<sup>Source:[Iwn](http://lwn.net/Articles/540996/)</sup>

> Flashcache is a module originally written and released by
>   Facebook(Mohan Srinivasan, Paul Saab and Vadim Tkachenko) in April of
>   2010. It is a kernel module that allows Writethrough caching of a drive on another drive. This is most often used for caching a
>   rotational drive on a smaller solid-state drive for performance
>   reasons. This gives you the speed of an SSD and the size of a standard
>   rotational drive for recently cached files.  FlashCache is a general
>   purpose writeback block cache for Linux.

<sup>Source:[ArchLinux](https://www.archlinux.org/)</sup>

> Bcache is a Linux kernel block layer cache. It allows one or more fast
>   disk drives such as flash-based solid state drives (SSDs) to act as a
>   cache for one or more slower hard disk drives.
>
> Hard drives are cheap and big, SSDs are fast but small and expensive.
>   Wouldn't it be nice if you could transparently get the advantages of
>   both? With Bcache, you can have your cake and eat it too.
>
> Bcache patches for the Linux kernel allow one to use SSDs to cache
>   other block devices. It's analogous to L2Arc for ZFS, but Bcache also
>   does writeback caching (besides just write through caching), and it's
>   filesystem agnostic. It's designed to be switched on with a minimum of
>   effort, and to work well without configuration on any setup. By
>   default it won't cache sequential IO, just the random reads and writes
>   that SSDs excel at. It's meant to be suitable for desktops, servers,
>   high end storage arrays, and perhaps even embedded.
>
> The design goal is to be just as fast as the SSD and cached device
>   (depending on cache hit vs. miss, and writethrough vs. writeback
>   writes) to within the margin of error. It's not quite there yet,
>   mostly for sequential reads. But testing has shown that it is
>   emphatically possible, and even in some cases to do better - primarily
>   random writes.

<sup>Source:[Bcache](http://bcache.evilpiepirate.org/)</sup>

Bcache  has a big disadvantage, and that it takes away memory from the system to implement the cache.

> EnhanceIO is a solution that runs beneath the application layer,
>   enabling applications to utilize the performance benefits of SSDs
>   without major IT infrastructure changes. An SSD cache can yield most
>   of the benefits of switching from HDDs to SSDs at a fraction of the
>   cost of an all-SSD system. A cached system typically operates on less
>   power than an HDD-based system of similar performance, and that
>   creates a side benefit by reducing cooling requirements.
>
> An SSD cache can also extend the useful life of an existing system by
>   improving performance to meet growing demands through an incremental
>   investment, rather than through a wholesale upgrade/replacement of the
>   existing system.
>
> Caching also enables faster access to the data without the extra
>   storage administration overhead to acquire and install new disk
>   shelves, configuring new LUNs and migrating data to the new LUNs.
>   Caching is almost transparent and requires little if any downtime.
>   EnhanceIO is based upon Flashcache.

<sup>Source:[Stec-Inc](http://www.stec-inc.com/products/enhanceio-ssd-cache-software/)</sup>

> bcache is the most worthless of all because it requires specially
>   prepared (formatted) data partition. This makes it difficult (if
>   possible) to attach cache to existing partition with data as one would
>   need 200% capacity and to perform long data-moving in order to
>   activate/deactivate caching.
>
> The brilliance of EnhanceIO is that it doesn't need intermediate
>   device at all and can be attached to any block device on-the-fly even
>   when device is already mounted. Another super-cool thing is that you
>   can attach EnhanceIO cache not just to partition but to partitioned
>   block device to cache all its partitions at once. Just like flashcache
>   enchanceio modules are built with DKMS and can be used with older
>   kernels.

<sup>Source: Debian</sup>

> DM Cache Advantages
>
> DM caches use a simplified architecture, which makes them adaptable
>   and easy to customize. Users can adjust the block size and the cache
>   capacity based on the amount of data it will have to handle or on the
>   value of the data. If a particular application needs to store a great
>   deal of data in sequence, users can configure the cache for that
>   purpose. If a user wants to record information in a database
>   simultaneously with the cache, that won't interfere with the cache's
>   operations.
>
> DM Cache Dis-Advantages
>
> One drawback to using a DM cache is that the Linux operating system
>   has limited space for storing metadata. If the cache is large, and
>   includes lots of small blocks, that adds up to a lot of metadata for
>   the stored information. To solve this problem, the user must increase
>   the block size. Another possible problem is that, after a server
>   crash, the cache metadata may no longer match the cache contents,
>   though it is possible to restore the correct configuration eventually.

<sup>Source: Complements of Fraser Sherman</sup>

So from the above information it’s clear that EnhanceIO is the way to go, but in my opinion since it’s based on Flashcache, I would go with flash cache.  But I will definitely try both of them before making a final decision.

Comment: EnhanceIO: a driver based on EhanceIO SSD caching software derived from Facebook's open source Flashcache project that's useful for using SSDs as cache devices for traditional HDDs. http://www.webupd8.org/2013/05/get-better-linux-desktop-performance.html

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Hopefully EnhanceIO will land in the 3.10 kernel and be available in the next Ubuntu release.

Comment: Nice writeup, but I must hightlight that DM cache is totally safe, if you experience a crash, you are not loosing any data of course. In practice, the cache could be less efficient for some time until metadata is regenerated.

Comment: The comment about bcache memory use is incorrect, so is the (quoted) one about conversion.

Comment: @Gabriel feel free to modify, but include the source.:)

Answer (score 1):

Feedback: I installed flashcache standard deb packages on Ubuntu about a year ago in write-back mode to cache /home (2TB) to a 50GB slice on a SSD.  It has performed wonderfully with no problems.  I have had a few X related "hangs" (ie not attributable to flashcache) and have used "Ctrl-Alt-PrtScr REISUB" a few times to recover with no problems and no corruption problems.
I used flashcache because a) there were debs available and b) it did not require a backup and restore of /home.