# Can flashcache be added to an existing drive without data loss?

Tags: flashcache

I have a raid 5 array that I'd like to cache. It already contains data (including OS - ubuntu 14.04). Is it possible to create a new flashcache volume without destroying the data?

It seems like flashcache_create man page doesn't mention this.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it's designed that way.

That's in my opinion the main advantage of flashcache and enhanceIO (see also: [What are the advantages/disadvantages of different SSD to HDD cacheing options (dm-cache, flashcashe...)?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/290502/what-are-the-advantages-disadvantages-of-different-ssd-to-hdd-cacheing-options))

I would still make a backup before the operation, just in case.