# Partition and file system scheme for Win 7 and Ubuntu 14 dual boot with UEFI and GPT

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, windows-7, uefi, filesystem

After looking through a lot of different guides and information on this site and others, I have a basic idea of a partitioning scheme to use for a dual boot Ubuntu-Win7 machine but I'm not so clear about file systems. I have a UEFI-supported board and I'm going to use the GPT partition type. I'd like to check to see if I'm on the right track or not.

My basic idea is: (updated to show Windows-required MSR partition)

```
sda1- EFI/ESP    FAT32    0.25gb
sda2- / (root)   EXT4     20gb
sda3- (MSR)      ----     0.13gb
sda4- win C:     NTFS     30gb
sda5- win D:     NTFS     500gb
sda6- /home      EXT4     300gb
sda7- (swap)     ???      16gb
```

Now on my single physical 1TB hard drive this leaves about 100gb and change unallocated for any future OS experiments or to make a shared drive between Windows and Ubuntu using some other file system if I run into problems.

For my allocated space NTFS is of course a natively supported Windows file system and seems to be fairly stable on Ubuntu so it sounds like the best choice for my Win partitions. I briefly looked at ExFAT but it sounds like it doesn't have as good of support on either Ubuntu or Windows so NTFS wins out.

The Ubuntu situation is less clear. I'm probably not going to be doing a lot of access of Ubuntu files from the Windows side and since it seems that there is a significant performance difference between EXT3 and EXT4, I decided to go with 4. EXT3 has more support but it doesn't look like it's necessarily better support (i.e. you have to open up a separate program to access EXT3 files). There is at least decent EXT4 file support in the form of ExtFS for Windows which works with the standard file management tools, and if that doesn't work then I probably can save my files directly to the NTFS D: drive from Ubuntu. The Swap partition from what I understand is a special "swap" file system, but I really had trouble finding any info on it.

From what I understand, the order of the two larger drives (Win D: and Ubuntu /home) doesn't matter so much but I should keep the two system drives (Win C: and Ubuntu root) close to the UEFI/ESP partition. Nothing I read talked about the order of the Swap partition at all and I saw partition schemes with it towards the beginning or at the end, so I'm guessing its order doesn't matter either.

Is this a reasonable setup or is there anything I'm getting wrong (size/system)? Does it make sense to have a separate Ubuntu Home and Windows Programs/Media partition, or would it make more sense to combine them as a big happy NTFS family? I'll probably be installing different versions of the same program on the Windows and Ubuntu side (like Steam and Eclipse IDE for example), so my instinct is to keep them separate and avoid confusion. If I do choose to add in a separate partition that is primarily for cross-platform work, what would be the best file system - NTFS? Something else? Is there anything else I should be aware of compatibility-wise by using EXT4 instead of the older EXT3?

I'm going to be switching over to mostly using Ubuntu but keeping Windows for gaming. As a long-time Windows user I have approximately a billion questions about Ubuntu but I'm going to start with just the partition and file format scheme for now.

Comment: hi, welcome to askubuntu! Two questions: are you sure you need 16GB swap? Or, better: are you sure you need swap? You need it if you are short in ram or if you want to use hibernation. 30GB to win7 SO... that isn't the best place to ask... but at glance I don't know if it's enough. Cheers

Comment: If partitioning in advance Windows also wants another partition. A 128KB system reserved just before the first NTFS partition. It is unformatted. If you have 8GB of RAM you do not need 16GB of swap. You can have just 2 or 3 GB for swap unless hibernating and if dual booting hibernating is not suggested. And where swap is on the drive is moot as it never (or almost never) will be used. I prefer configurations with smaller system partitions and larger /home and/or data partitions as you are planning. /home cannot be NTFS, but you can have a smaller /home or include it in /  if using a NTFS data.

Comment: Hmmm, well I was at first thinking that I wouldn't need so much swap, but later I decided I would put it in anyway since I have plenty of hard drive space and then just in case I decide later down the road to use the hibernate function then I would have it available as an option. @oldfred - the 128kb system reserved partition isn't the EFI/ESP? I had thought they were the same thing. Does it really only need 128kb?

Comment: Microsoft suggested partitions including reserved partition for gpt & UEFI:
http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd744301%28WS.10%29.aspx
And: Order on drive is important: msftres
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Reserved_Partition

Comment: Actually, on the Wiki entry it sounds like the MSR partition is mandatory for GPT drives. I'll update my original partition list to show it.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu. Please ask one question at a time. Answers to many of your questions would be opinion based. What seems reasonable (or make sense) to me won't be for someone else. This is not the right forum for such questions. See [help](http://askubuntu.com/help). Most of the questions that can be objectively answered have been answered in comments. See http://askubuntu.com/questions/295773/i-want-to-reformat-my-home-partition-from-ext3-to-ntfs/295784#295784 for the issues with `/home` in NTFS. @oldfred you may want to convert some of your comments to a full answer.

Comment: I understand opinion/discussion is not the purpose of this forum, but I was hoping that using the term "reasonable" would broaden the question beyond opinion -- i.e. we might have differences of opinion about the use of X file format, but you could tell me at least that it's within reason to use it even if you don't agree with me. What I'd really like would be some kind of pro/con about the file formats, but I have listed my initial guesses as a starting point. Pros and cons for the formats I think would not be opinion based.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I will try to answer as many of your questions as I can:

**Is this a reasonable setup or is there anything I'm getting wrong (size/system)?**

What is reasonable for one user may not be for another. This is because we all use our computers for different purposes, and in different ways. As others have pointed out:

- You probably wont need 16GB Swap. 2GB should be enough.
- 30GB C: for Windows system partition may be too small.

However, these are your choices. The rest seems OK to me.

**Does it make sense to have a separate Ubuntu Home and Windows Programs/Media 
partition, or would it make more sense to combine them as a big happy `NTFS` family?**

You can't put the Ubuntu `/home` partition in the `NTFS` format. Ubuntu keeps its user configurations in the `/home` for each user. Each user has her ownership and read/write permissions. Ubuntu cannot use `NTFS` for storing ownership and permissions. It needs to be one of the Linux compatible partition formats, such as `ext2`, `ext3`, `ext4`, `zfs`, `btfs`, etc. As you know Windows on its own does not understand any of these partition formats. So it is best to keep them separate and use their respective native formats, `NTFS` for Windows, and `ext4` for Ubuntu.

See [I want to reformat my home partition from ext3 to ntfs](https://askubuntu.com/questions/295773/i-want-to-reformat-my-home-partition-from-ext3-to-ntfs/295784#295784) for more on this.

**If I do choose to add in a separate partition that is primarily for cross-platform work, what would be the best file system - `NTFS`? Something else?**

I don't think you need a separate partition for cross-platform work, but if you do, it should be `NTFS`. You can share `sda5` or `D:` in `NTFS`  with Ubuntu. I recommend you create soft links of specific folders from `sda5` (`D:`) to `sda6` (`/home`). For example:

`D:\user\[yourID_in_windows]\Java_Workspace` can be soft-linked to `/home/[yourID_in_Ubuntu]/Java_Workspace`

See [Do I need Intel Smart Response when installing Ubuntu?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/282831/do-i-need-intel-smart-response-when-installing-ubuntu/282903#282903) for an example of how to create soft-links of specific folders between two drives. The same commands can be used for creating soft links between `NTFS` and `ext4` partitions. If you want you can keep all your music, video, etc. in `D:` and have links in your `/home` partition.

**Is there anything else I should be aware of compatibility-wise by using `ext4` instead of the older `ext3?`**

`ext4` is a mature partition format used by default in Ubuntu. You have nothing to worry about if you stick to `ext4`.

Hope this helps

Comment: Thank you! I'm still working on getting the two to load correctly but that's an issue with booting into UEFI and so an issue for another forum.