# Install ONLY Ubuntu OS on SSD (22gb) [Samsung NP530]

Tags: ssd, system-installation

install ubuntu on the SSD and all apps and documents in the HDD. Can i?

Comment: See my answer to a similar question http://askubuntu.com/questions/282831/do-i-need-intel-smart-response-when-installing-ubuntu

Comment: @user68186 you can link your answer straightforward with the share button. http://askubuntu.com/a/282903/95393 . By the way, nice answer (+1)

Answer (score 0):

Yes. The OS is the root filesystem or /. The other stuff will fall under /home. During partitioning, do a manual partitioning and set the two drives as such. Don't forget to make your OS bootable.

For example

```
SSD:
14GB /
8GB   swap

HDD:
500GB /home
```

Comment: programs instal in "/home"? sure?

Comment: Most programs will go in `/`. There are some exceptions, such as Windows programs under wine. However, there is no easy way to change this Linux does not keep all programs in a single folder like Windows.