# Best way to set up my drives for Ubuntu

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, hard-drive, ssd

I am currently running Windows 8.1 (booting from a 256gb SSD and using a 1TB HDD for extra storage).  I have an extra 500GB HDD sitting around that I was going to use for Ubuntu as dual boot but I don't necessarily want to boot from disk--I've gotten used to my 10 second start ups.  Would it make sense to partition a small amount of my SSD (~15GB) for Ubuntu system files and some programs and then have the extra HDD for additional storage?

I hope this makes sense but, if no, feel free to comment on my question?.

Comment: [This answer](http://askubuntu.com/questions/282831/do-i-need-intel-smart-response-when-installing-ubuntu/282903#282903) was meant for a single-boot Ubuntu system. But it has the basics of what you want in terms of setting up the drive system. I suggest a 30GB partition in the SSD for the OS and share the 1TB HDD for all the data. Keep the 500 GB HDD for backup (or the other way around).

Answer (score 0):

You could partition your SSD and install the OS there. This will give you the quick startup time you desire.

What sort of things do you plan to install on the Ubuntu partition? If you run out of space and have to start installing on the slower drive then your speed will be limited to that of the slower drive anyway.