# Recommended Ubuntu partition size

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, ssd

I have a 128GB SSD with Windows 10 installed on it and I also have a 1TB HDD on my computer. I want to dual boot Ubuntu along side with windows 10 but I don't know how much space I need to give to Ubuntu and if I should even install it on the same drive as windows, because I roughly have 60GB's on my SSD left but I thought it would be better to keep them like that since windows always has updates and that sort of stuff.
I mainly use windows for gaming and pretty much everything, Ubuntu is for college programming purposes.

Sorry if I misnamed any term but I'm still a beginner to all this sort of stuff.

Comment: You may also use the partition and data allocation between SSD and HDD from the answer to this question: [Do I need Intel Smart Response when installing Ubuntu?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/282831/do-i-need-intel-smart-response-when-installing-ubuntu/282903?s=4|26.7736#282903)

Answer (score 1):

Although this question has many possibilities, according to the needs of each one.

I would install in particular:

An ext4 partition, of 1 gigabytes, for /boot in the SDD.

An ext4 partition of 30 gigabytes for /on the HDD.

A partition exchange system, of 4 gigas to swap on the HDD.

An ext4 partition, of 40 gigabytes, for /home on the HDD.

Comment: Most desktops do not need /boot partition. And swap is not a partition exchange system, but more for use if RAM if full of active programs. Ubuntu with 17.04 or later  does not create a swap partition, but uses a swap file, but will use an existing swap if found. How much for /home or /mnt/data whether NTFS or ext4 depends greatly on how much data you want or will have.

Comment: I would prefer to do not have separate swap partition and to setup a [swap file](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-add-swap-space-on-ubuntu-16-04) instead that. Separate boot partition is required when you are using LVM, etc.