# Ubuntu installation problem with Intel Rapid Storage Technology

Tags: system-installation, 20.04, sata, rst

I apologize immediately for my English

After buying a new notebook, Acer aspire A514-52-59EQ, with pre-installed Windows 10 home I wanted to go back to my dear old Ubuntu, in the new version 20.04LTS, specific that I have already tried with Ubuntu18.04 LTS, 19.10 and other various distributions Linux.

I have obviously disabled secure boot and quick start of windows.

During the installation, however, the warning of incompatibility with intel RST appears.Following the guide to which the warning refers, a request is made to change the SATA mode in AHCI from the Uefi Bios.

The problem is that inside the BIOS my SATA device is in "optane whitout raid" mode, but in the itntel optane app this is disable, and I cannot modify it in any way.

My storage controller is Intel SATA / Pcle RST premium controller chipset. Intel told me to uninstall it quietly, although I was doubtful that it managed the disk, I ignorantly trusted, I did it and the only thing that caused it was the inability to access the disk resulting in the necessary restore.

Instead, by contacting the Acer, they was told me that it is possible to create a Live USB in order to overcome the problem, but that since it was not their responsibility, we could not say more.

Can someone help me?

Thank you

Comment: See https://discourse.ubuntu.com/t/ubuntu-installation-on-computers-with-intel-r-rst-enabled/15347 for the current Ubuntu documentation on RST.

Comment: thanks, I I have seen the guide but i  can't  change the hard disk controller type to AHCI in my BIOS.

Comment: See https://askubuntu.com/questions/282831/do-i-need-intel-smart-response-when-installing-ubuntu/282903#282903

Answer (score 0):

In the new UEfI BIOS acer hysde20 version 1.12 the hard disk controller type is not visibile, to be able to change it you need to enter the main page and press CTRL + S, at which point the hard disk controller type item will appear with the possibility of changing from optane without raid to AHCI

Beyond this, the secureboot and the quick start of windows must obviously be disabled

At that point you can install Ubuntu.

If you dedicate the whole disk to ubunutu we can proceed directly to the installation of Ubuntu without doing anything else.

If instead, as I did, you want dual boot Ubuntu and Windows. Windows will no longer start if you do not change any keys in the registry first. It will therefore be necessary to start windows in safe mode and go to modify the following:

Start Registry Editor and then:

HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE \ SYSTEM \ CurrentControlSet \ Services \ iaStorV \ startoverride HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE \ SYSTEM \ CurrentControlSet \ Services \ storahci \ startoverride

Both must be changed to 0.

It is important that it is done in safe mode otherwise it will not work.

Once this is done, restart your computer and proceed with the Ubuntu installation.