# How to partition for Windows/Ubuntu dual boot on same SSD and on same HDD? [

Tags: partitioning, hard-drive, windows, ssd, boot-partition

I have a 256gb SSD and a 1tb HDD on mu laptop.

I want to create a dual boot and add a linux OS (with ubuntu) on my SSD.

but, I have only 160 gb free out of the 256, so i'd rather install the OS and only the OS on the SSD and then use part of the HDD for the linux.

I mean I want to use the SSD only to store both systems, and then also split the hdd and use it for both of them as well.

Is it possible? Can it ruin something? the use of one ssd for 2 systems? How can I split the HDD to both of them?

I'll try to be more specific. As I said I have free 160gb out of 256gb on my C:\ SSD which already got Windows on it. I want to also install Linux on it. But when i'll be working on Linux, i'll probably download stuff, apps, documents, create projects and etc, which will consume memory and I don't want it to consume memory of the C:\ SSD, I want it to consume memory from my D:\ HDD which got free 1GB.

In that way I won't be "scared" to download and create many things that will consume alot of space because I won't care about the space because I got plenty of it on my HDD unline my SSD which got only 160 free gb, and i'll allocate another 50gb for the linux which means it will reduce to 110 free gb, and I don't want it to be reduced any more and I would prefer to use the space that on my 1TB HDD for my projects and things.

Thanks.

Comment: @user68186 Hey, thanks for your comment. I'll try to be more specific. As I said I have free 160gb out of 256gb on my C:\ SSD which already got Windows on it. I want to also install Linux on it. But when i'll be working on Linux, i'll probably download stuff, apps, documents, create projects and etc, which will consume memory and I don't want it to consume memory of the C:\ SSD, I want it to consume memory from my D:\ HDD which got free 1GB.

Comment: You can put `/home` in your HDD. However, see the question I have linked above. There is no easy way to install apps in another drive in Ubuntu. Steam games are an exception. Your coding projects will be in your `/home` folder. If you put `/home` in your HDD, then all your files, photos, music, codes, etc. will be in the HDD.

Comment: @user68186 yeah, this is what I want. Because codes, photos, files can use a lot of space which I won't necessary have on my SSD and 70gb isn't enough, correct me if i'm wrong.

Comment: Please read all the references at the bottom of the answer I have linked above. Many years ago SSDs were only 32 GB or 64 GB. Even then I recommended putting `/home` in the SSD and linking the big folders within `/home` to the HDD.  Particularly, read [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/282831/what-is-recommended-as-optimal-ssdhdd-setup-for-ubuntu). Note, these days you don't need a separate swap partition, as Ubuntu uses a swap file by default.