# Move unused space to root or home - installation went wrong

Tags: partitioning, disk-usage

I made screenshots of Gparted

Image 1
Can I get that unused space in to the root partition?
Can I delete the EFI system partition to get the space?
https://i.stack.imgur.com/qPBXY.jpg

Image 2
Can I delete the EFI system partition
Can I delete the Microsoft Reserved partition
https://i.stack.imgur.com/yt8lg.jpg

I would like to delete unnecessary partitions and get the space too the root.

This part is solved.
I linked my folders in Home and moved the data to Partition 3 as suggested in the comments. The Snap folder didn't work to link and this will become big with all new apps like Gimp etc.
It seems difficult to move the snap folder.

I wanted to make a clean Ubuntu install, without any windows partition. But when I started to use it I discovered that the windows partition was there with over 900GB. I deleted it and it gave me that amount of unused space.

There it says that there are 2 disks INTEL SSD 14GB
with 2 partitions P1 EFI system 537 MB P2 Linux filesystem Mounted at Filesystem Root 14 GB 81% full. I have not added anything yet because of all the problems.
and 1.0 TB Hard drive TOSHIBA where all this unused space is in p3
Partition 1 /dev/sda1 EFI System 105 MB
Partition 2 Microsoft Reserved
Partition 3 with is the biggest
Really I don't want any partition

Or is it better in my case to make a new Ubuntu installation and try to wipe out all the old partitions? I wish I could, if not it is no more space in the root for more partitions.

Comment: See https://help.ubuntu.com/community/HowtoPartition/ResizingPartition

Comment: You also can move /home into that space, you need a new ext4 partition. Or just move all your data in /home in to that space. To move /home uses rsync- Be sure to use parameters to preserve ownership & permissions 
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Partitioning/Home/Moving  & https://askubuntu.com/questions/1013677/storing-data-on-second-hdd-mounting & 
https://askubuntu.com/questions/1058756/installing-all-applications-on-a-ssd-disk-and-putting-all-files-on-hdd-disk

Comment: I am going to try to move the home directory as you have suggested.  Meanwhile is it possible to delete some of the other partitions as I do not want windows dual boot. Can I delete this partition Microsoft Reserved Partition? Thank you both for the answers.

Comment: In Ubuntu, install Gparted if you can. If not boot from the Ubuntu Installation USB and select **Try Ubuntu**. open Gparted (it is already there in the USB) and take two screenshots: 1. The 14GB SSD, 2. the other 1TB HDD. Upload the screenshots in imgur.com and edit your question and add links to these two screenshots in your question. This will help us understand the situation better. In theory if you don't want any files, pictures, etc, from the Windows partitions, you can delete all the partitions in the 1TB HDD.

Comment: Some computers use a small SSD (14GB in your case) as cache. It is called "Intel Smart Response" or some such thing. [See this question and my answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/282831/do-i-need-intel-smart-response-when-installing-ubuntu) to understand this better.