# drives will not mount on startup

Tags: mount, startup

I am simply trying to have a few drives mount at startup of UBUNTU 12.04. I have tried entering the commands in startup applications (as explained in [THIS](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/AutomaticallyMountPartitions#Per-User_Mounts) tutorial):

> udisksctl mount --block-device /dev/disk/by-uuid/32249C132BD865 (shortened)
>
> udisksctl mount --block-device /dev/disk/by-uuid/FCE456F556B21E (shortened)
>
> udisksctl mount --block-device /dev/disk/by-uuid/6A8C95BE8C958B (shortened)

After reboot the drives are not mounted. I can mount them simply by clikcing on the icons in pcmanfm or nautilus, but they remain unmounted at startup.

I have also tried to edit the /etc/fstab file as drescribed in the ANSWER [HERE](https://askubuntu.com/questions/268046/mount-two-hard-drives-on-start-up) but can not locate any folder named "fstab", only a folder named "fstab.d" which seems to be empty.

I should also mention that the filesystems are NTFS

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found another tutorial online (sorry lost the link on startup), but it was suggested there that for NTFS file systems that I get a utility called
NTFS Configuration Too. It worked like a charm!

Answer (score 2):

The tutorial you followed was for enabling per-user automatic drive mounting within the graphical desktop.  If you want the drive to be mounted at boot, regardless of user or graphical desktop, you do it with `/etc/fstab`, which is much simpler.

I'm not sure why the udisks method failed for you, but it isn't the approach I would take.

Your question seems to be confused about whether `/etc/fstab` is a file or folder.  `/etc/fstab` is a file, which you should edit with a text editor.

User-friendly documentation for it is available here:

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Fstab

Comment: thank you for clearing up that file/folder issue. I was so confused! In any case I found NTFS configuration tool was enough to mount the drives.