# two different disks used by a root partition?

Tags: filesystem

I have windows and linux dual boot, each of them in different physical disk. 
As i no longer need to boot to windows, how can i add that disk to linux root partition? Can a root partition uses two disks? Thanks.

Comment: See https://askubuntu.com/questions/22215/why-have-both-mnt-and-media and https://askubuntu.com/questions/268046/mount-two-hard-drives-on-start-up You can mount partition(s) from the old Windows disk anywhere in the Linux file system.

Comment: You can use 2 disks for the root partition. By using RAID, or using bcache for example. Or LVM as already mentionned.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot "share" the root partition over two disks. You will need to mount the second disk somewhere.

**Idea 1 - Use it as a drive from file manager**

Format the disk using your favorite formatting utility and mount it in your file manager. This should be the easiest option.

**Idea 2 - Use it for your /home folder**

You could use this other disk as your /home by following the tutorial here: [How to Move Home Directory to New Partition or Disk in Linux](https://www.tecmint.com/move-home-directory-to-new-partition-disk-in-linux/)